# jQuery: hide form submit button but keep functionality

Tags: jquery

How can I hide the form submit button but keep its functionality (typing Return/Enter in  submits form)?

Using `.hide()` (or `display:none` via CSS) removes the submit on return functionality.

Comment: Hitting enter/return to submit a form is already the default behavior

Comment: @helion3 is correct. Do you have some other code there that might be interfering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `display: none;`, use `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: That leaves space in the DOM--not usually a desirable effect.

Comment: This is an important distinction. Using "visibility: hidden" will allow events to reach the object while "display: none" won't.

Comment: @isherwood: You can always use CSS to change the sizing or otherwise address what you're describing. The idea here is that visibility: hidden; will still allow the button to be present and functional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it would be necessary, but you can use this type of CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/58Y76

```
input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}
```

This puts an element offscreen without scrollbars.

Comment: That could result in the user getting a long horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Nope. I use it all the time for accessibility.

Comment: See fiddle. I'd be interested to know if anyone gets scrollbars in edge-case browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I used a `<button id="tmp"></button>` instead of `<input type="submit"></input>`.

And then in CSS:

```
#tmp{
  display:none
}
```